# Why does scipy.griddata return nans with 'cubic' interpolation if input 'values' contains nan?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, nan, cubic

I want to perform cubic interpolation of an array that contains some `nan` values using `scipy.griddata`. However, as soon as a single `nan` is present in the `values` parameter, the returned interpolation is filled with only `nan`. This is not the case when using the 'nearest' or the 'linear' interpolation methods.

What is the reason for this behavior and is there a simple way to ignore nans in the `values` input?

This is a minimal working example, adapted from [griddata scipy interpolation not working (giving nan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656489/griddata-scipy-interpolation-not-working-giving-nan):

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:10j, 0:1:10j]
points = np.random.rand(100, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

values[0]=np.nan # now add a single nan value to the array

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest') # no nans here
grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear') # this has nans on the edges (as expected)
grid_z2 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic') # this is filled only with nans.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to remove all `nan` from the `points` and `values` input arrays prior to interpolating the data. `numpy` can be used efficiently for doing so:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:10j, 0:1:10j]
points = np.random.rand(100, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

values[0]=np.nan # now add a single nan value to the array

#Find all the indexes where there is no nan neither in values nor in points.
nonanindex=np.invert(np.isnan(points[:,0]))*np.invert(np.isnan(points[:,1]))*np.invert(np.isnan(values))

#Remove the nan using fancy indexing. griddata can now properly interpolate. The result will have nan only on the edges of the array
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
grid_z2 = riddata(np.stack((points[nonanindex,0],points[nonanindex,1]),axis=1), values[nonanindex], (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

While this solves the problem, I  did not answer yet why this issue of the griddata function only appears for a cubic interpolation.